# Manual hdbios Entry in Refind

Tags: boot, partitioning, refind

I have a Multiboot Setup on 2 Hardisks using Refind.
HDD 1 has GPT Partition Scheme and it has UEFI Supported Operating Systems.
HDD 2 has MBR Partition Scheme and has Windows XP Installed along with 1 Data Partition.
UEFI Supported Operating Systems Boot fine using the Refind.
When I enabled **scanfor hdbios**, there was an entry for Boot Legacy from HDD 2, and successfully booted into Windows XP.
My Question is that Can I add a MANUAL Entry for "BOOT FROM HDD 2 using HDBIOS" and name it something like "Windows XP" Instead of Refind searching for All Possible Options to boot from, in hdbios.
Moreover, is there any possibility to Boot an MBR-Based Partition, such as HD(1,1) or (HD1,2) using HDBIOS, by loading the Partition Boot Sector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rEFInd does not currently support manual BIOS/CSM/legacy boot stanzas. You can adjust the icon by creating a new `os_legacy.png` icon, ideally in a directory specified by `icons_dir` in `refind.conf` so that your new icon won't be overwritten if/when you upgrade rEFInd. See [the rEFInd theming documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/themes.html#icons) for more on this subject.